# How can I hide a certain part of my footer in specific page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide fixed-button id and anilogg_buddypress class from my login page How can I achieve this in WordPress?

```
function anilogg_footer() {?>
    <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width:481px){
        .fixed-menu{
            display:none;
        }
    #fixed-button{
    display:none;
}
     }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.fixed-menu{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        background:white;
        height:50px;
        border-top:1px solid #e40000;
    }
    .fixed-menu li {
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center;
        color:#e40000;
        width:23%;
        line-height:50px;
        font-size:1.5rem;

  }
    .fixed-menu li:2n{
        border-left:1px solid #fff;
    }
    #fixed-button a{
        display:block;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background:#e40000;
        color:white;
        position:fixed;
        right:15px;
        bottom:65px;
        border-radius:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:50px;
        font-size:2rem;
    }
}
    </style>   
        <div id="fixed-button">
        <a href="#" class="fixed-menu">
        <span class="icon-videocam"></span>
        </a>
        </div>
      <div class="anilogg_buddypress">
        <ul class="fixed-menu">
    <li><span class="icon-home"></span></li>
    <li><span class="icon-mail"> </span></li>
    <li><span class="icon-bell"></span></li>
    <li><span class="icon-user"></span></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'anilogg_footer' );

    if(is_page('login')){
    ?>
    <style>
    .fixed-menu{
        display:none;
    }
    #fixed-button{
    display:none;
    }
        </style>
    <?php }
    else{
    }
```

I expect that the anilogg_buddypress class and fixed-button id div should not be visible on the login page. (There is a page named login Not default login page of WordPress). I have made function anilogg_footer for displaying a bottom menu in the website. For which I have added a action.

Comment: what is your `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'anilogg_footer' );` for? and is this code in your functions.php?

Comment: I have edited the code please go through it.

Comment: You should have the `if(is_page('login')){` inside your function. not as a stand alone

Comment: Or, you could put that styling inside your template for login.